# Custom Edit text: InputType

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-view, android-custom-view, android-textinputedittext

I have created a custom EditText and trying to set its inputType to numberPassword but its still showing me digits.

**What I tried:**

1. Add inputType in onDraw method of CustomEditText class.
2. Setting transformation method.

But still not working.

**Current State of my custom EditText:**
I am not setting inputType anywhere in the custom editText. I am only setting it in xml file just like below:

```
android:inputType="numberPassword"
```

Any help will be much appreciated regarding if there is any custom editText settings required in CustomEditText class.

Answer (score 2):

this work for me.

```
mEdit.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: hi Mohammad, Thanks for your answer. I also tried it but its not working for me. I also edited my question.